# In SPARQL SELECT, keep only one record when their values are equals but in opposite order (the first is x,y and the second is y,x)

Tags: xml, sparql, owl, ontology, rdfs

I'm learning SPARQL and I'm trying to do a query on a movie ontology I wrote myself. I would like to extract from it all the the actors who worked together in a movie, so I wrote this:

```
PREFIX  exID: <http://example.org/#> 
PREFIX  rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?actorName1 ?actorName2 
WHERE {     
    ?actor rdfs:label ?actorName1 .
    ?actor exID:recitaIn ?movie .
    {
        SELECT DISTINCT ?actorName2 ?movie2 
        WHERE {
            ?actor2 rdfs:label ?actorName2 .
            ?actor2 exID:recitaIn ?movie2 .
        }
    }
    FILTER (?movie = ?movie2 && ?actorName1 != ?actorName2)
}
```

Now this works, but not really in the way I want, because it writes two times the same actors but in opposite order. To be more clear, this will have as output:

| actorName1 | actorName2 |
| --- | --- |
| "Jack Nicholson" | "Leonardo DiCaprio" |
| "Leonardo DiCaprio" | "Jack Nicholson" |

but I would like to have just one of this two rows because they represents conceptually the same thing. How can I accomplish this?

I will leave the significant part of the ontology here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE ontology [
  <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XLMSchema#">
]>

<rdf:RDF    
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:owl ="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:xsd ="http://www.w3.org/2001/XLMSchema#"

    xml:base="http://example.org/"
    xmlns:exID="http://example.org/#"
 >

    <!--    Ontology Properties -->
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about=""> 
    </owl:Ontology>

    <!--    Class declarations  -->
    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Regista">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Regista</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Director</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="it">Responsabile artistico e tecnico di un'opera</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">Artistic and technical manager of a creative work</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Troupe">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Troupe</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Troupe</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="it">L'insieme delle figure professionali, tecniche, artistiche ed amministrative che realizzano un film</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">The group of professional, technical and artistics figures which realize a movie</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Cast">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Troupe" />
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Cast</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Cast</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="it">L'insieme degli attori che compaiono nel film</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">Ensemble of the actors who appear in the movie</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Attore">
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Cast" />
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Attore</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Actor</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="it">Rappresenta un personaggio in un'opera creativa</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">Portrays a character in a creative work</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:Class>
    
    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Film">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Film</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Movie</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="it">Un lavoro di arte visuale utilizzato per simulare esperienze che comunica idee, storie, percezioni, sentimenti, bellezza o atmosfera tramite l'utilizzo di immagini in movimento.</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">A work of visual art used to simulate experiences that communicate ideas, stories, perceptions, feelings, beauty, or atmosphere through the use of moving images.</rdfs:comment>
    </owl:Class>
    
    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Pellicola">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Pellicola</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Movie</rdfs:label>
        <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="#Film" />
    </owl:Class>

    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Attore_Comico">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Attore Comico</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Comic Actor</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="it">Un attore che prova a intrattenere il pubblico facendolo ridere</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">An actor who seeks to entertain an audience by making them laugh</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Attore" />
    </owl:Class>
    
    <owl:Class rdf:about="#Attore_Drammatico">
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="it">Attore Drammatico</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Dramatic Actor</rdfs:label>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="it">Un attore specializzato in ruoli dal forte sviluppo psicologico ed emotivo</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:comment xml:lang="en">An actor specialized in roles with an huge psychological and emotional development</rdfs:comment>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Attore" />
    </owl:Class>


    <!--    Properties declarations -->
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#dirige">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Regista" />
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Film" />
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
    
    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#compareIn">
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Attore" />
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Film" />
    </owl:ObjectProperty>

    <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#recitaIn">
        <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="#compareIn" />
    </owl:ObjectProperty>


    <!--    Instances   -->    
    <rdf:Description rdf:about="theWolfOfWallStreet">
        <rdfs:label>The Wolf Of Wall Street</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Film"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="theDeparted">
        <rdfs:label>The Departed</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Film"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="gangsNY">
        <rdfs:label>Gangs of New York</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Film"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="aviator">
        <rdfs:label>The Aviator</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Film"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="killersFlowerMoon">
        <rdfs:label>Killers of the Flower Moon</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Film"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="shutterIsland">
        <rdfs:label>Shutter Island</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Film"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="diCaprio">
        <rdfs:label>Leonardo di Caprio</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Attore_Drammatico"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Attore_Comico"/>
        <exID:recitaIn rdf:resource="theWolfOfWallStreet"/>
        <exID:recitaIn rdf:resource="theDeparted"/>
        <exID:recitaIn rdf:resource="gangsNY"/>
        <exID:recitaIn rdf:resource="aviator"/>
        <exID:recitaIn rdf:resource="shutterIsland"/>
        <exID:recitaIn rdf:resource="killersFlowerMoon"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="nicholson">
        <rdfs:label>Jack Nicholson</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Attore_Drammatico"/>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Attore_Comico"/>
        <exID:recitaIn rdf:resource="theDeparted"/>
    </rdf:Description>

    <rdf:Description rdf:about="scorsese">
        <rdfs:label>Martin Scorsese</rdfs:label>
        <rdf:type rdf:resource="#Regista"/>
        <exID:dirige rdf:resource="theWolfOfWallStreet"/>
        <exID:dirige rdf:resource="theDeparted"/>
        <exID:dirige rdf:resource="gangsNY"/>
        <exID:dirige rdf:resource="shutterIsland"/>
        <exID:dirige rdf:resource="aviator"/>
        <exID:dirige rdf:resource="killersFlowerMoon"/>
    </rdf:Description>
    
    <owl:AllDifferent>
        <owl:distinctMembers rdf:parseType="Collection">
            <exID:Attore rdf:about="diCaprio" />
            <exID:Attore rdf:about="nicholson" />
       </owl:distinctMembers>
    </owl:AllDifferent>
    
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: `&& ?actorName1 > ?actorName2` (if they are not full namesakes).

Comment: there is also no need for a subquery, just do `?actor rdfs:label ?actorName1 .
    ?actor exID:recitaIn ?movie . ?actor2 rdfs:label ?actorName2 .?actor2 exID:recitaIn ?movie .`

Comment: Oh you're right... I was overcomplicating things thanks @UninformedUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer for my problem was in [the comment by *UninformedUser*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71165310/in-sparql-select-keep-only-one-record-when-their-values-are-equals-but-in-oppos/75223700#comment125802166_71165310):

```
?actor rdfs:label ?actorName1 .     
?actor exID:recitaIn ?movie .
?actor2 rdfs:label ?actorName2. 
?actor2 exID:recitaIn ?movie .
```

Without any subquery at all. This will correctly display:

| actorName1 | actorName2 |
| --- | --- |
| "Jack Nicholson" | "Leonardo DiCaprio" |

as output, without any duplicates.